# Ext-js : Unable to show data on calendar panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar, sencha-cmd

I am trying to add calendar panel to a web application. But i am unable to display events on calendar.

Here is the code:

```
{
    xtype: 'calendar',
    layout: 'fit',
    flex: 7,
    align: 'stretch',
    autoHeight: true,

    views: {
        day: {
            startTime: 6,
            endTime: 22
        },
        workweek: {
            xtype: 'calendar-week',
            titleTpl: '{start:date("j M")} - {end:date("j M")}',
            label: 'Work Week',
            weight: 15,
            dayHeaderFormat: 'D d',
            firstDayOfWeek: 1,
            visibleDays: 5
        }
    },
    timezoneOffset: 0
    store: {
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'calendar.ext',
        }
    }

    }
```

The Ajax call returns the below data:

```
    {

  "Data": [
    {
      "id": "153_0",
      "calendarId": 47,
      "title": "BELC21 > 153 > Mango",
      "startDate": "2016-08-19T00:00:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2016-08-31T00:00:00-05:00",
      "allDay": true
    }
]}
```

If somebody could help me with how should i display the events on calendar through either with data in memory or the dynamic data.

Answer (score 3):

you have to configured your store to autoSync, this will send the events back as they are saved .